# Which package contains EC2 kernel in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, amazon-ec2

In Lucid Lynx (10.04 LTS) I used linux-image-ec2 package which is not available any more.
I need a package containing those files (or newer)

- vmlinuz-2.6.32-345-ec2
- initrd.img-2.6.32-345-ec2

Using those images for xen based virtual hosts with pygrub.

Comment: I found my package: linux-image-virtual - Linux kernel image for virtual machines

Answer (score 1):

I found my package: **linux-image-virtual** - Linux kernel image for virtual machines

Answer (score 0):

[How about this website](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/xen/)?

[image]

Comment: Not so sure about it. As I already wrote in the comment for your post which you probably deleted. I need an ubuntu package which can be installed with apt-get install and create the files mentioned above in the /boot directory.

Comment: Why apt-get? And I can tell you you are not going to get deb files for these since they have not been created since natty. ;)

Comment: I did not know that those packages are not created any more. Maybe therefore I could not locate them in the first place.

I just do not feel comfortable because there is no versioning information for those files. But I will try them out later and let you know if it worked or not.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Unfortunately it is not what I need but pretty close. It is a kernel for installer. I could boot it and it started asking installation related questions. I have already set up everything so I need something else.